# The API which tells the cassandra cluster is overloaded or not

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have java application which uses datastax drive to communicate with cassandra. I have a requirement to query cassandra only if it is not overloaded.
At application level (not manually ) how would i know cassandra is overloaded or not? Is datastax provide any such api ?? I am looking for method something like boolean isCassOverloded() ..Kindly help me in this.

THanks for the answers .. Just trying to be more specific the stat's I am more interested in checking 'live size' and 'key count' of a Column Family. I know nodetool --host  cfstats gives both value but in java using datastax how i would I get both? If datastax does not provide such api so is there any rest api exposed by cassandra which give this information?

Comment: Another way to accomplish this is by implementing circuit breakers or by using a framework with a built in health API. See .https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/circuit-breaker/#programmatic-example and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-health-indicators. Your client can determine the health of Cassandra by hitting a health endpoint AND/OR determine the cluster is in a bad state based on the level of exceptions the client sees. For example, if the cluster is reporting that it is unavailable, then why bother sending more requests. This is a more robust solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

> At application level (not manually ) how would i know cassandra is overloaded or not? Is datastax provide any such api ?? I am looking for method something like boolean isCassOverloded()

Simple answer, such magic API does not exist. Providing such API on a driver level would require:

1. Being able to define what is a **healthy** node compared to an **overloaded** node
2. Being able to collect the health status of **any** node in the cluster in real time
3. Being able to propagate this health status to all nodes in the cluster without hammering the local network

Point 1. is pretty hard to achieve because node health may depends on various hardware factor (CPU usage, disk I/O, ...) and getting those infos will require installing system agents on all those machines

Point 2. and 3. are already implemented by the Gossip protocol but the Gossip only tells you wether the node is UP/DOWN and its level of suspicion, not if a node is overloaded or idle

To be notified of the status of any node (UP or DOWN), you can register a host status listerner on the driver: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Host.StateListener.html

Comment: thanks for answer. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by overloaded cassandra?

It's very vague. Nodes cpu usage or db connection usages, or ongoing number of queries on each connection.

Anyways, this is what you need to do

https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/features/pooling/#monitoring-and-tuning-the-pool

Use the code provided, to monitor connection status, and accordingly decide if you want to fire query.

Comment: thanks for answer. number of current request may not solve my issue . Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra exposes MBeans objects via the jmx url. You can use JConsole as described [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_monitoring_c.html) to see what indicators are exposed. Look at `org.apache.cassandra.metrics`.

Your java client application can connect to the cluster via a jmx connection to gather those information. Then you have to choose heuristics to decide whether or not your cluster is overloaded. What about using ClientRequest.Read.Latency as follow :

```
Boolean cluster_overloaded = read_latency > read_request_timeout / 5
```

read_request_timeout is a constant value : the one you set in your cassandra.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

> If datastax does not provide such api so is there any rest api exposed by cassandra which give this information?

You can access those information by hitting the JMX API itself. The Cassandra server exposes all those metrics through the JMX interface.

All that you need is a tool to fetch those information.

Look at Jolokia: https://jolokia.org/

- Spicing up JMX with Jolokia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIiauuynfmA

Answer (score 0):

So This is how I implemented finally:
I am getting "Count" attribute of below  metric using Java.management api.
"org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,keyspace=mykeyspace,scope=myCF,name=LiveDiskSpaceUsed" 
And comparing at service layer that if it is greater than for example 350 MB ..then assume that the cassandra is overloaded.
Note: The abovelogic is as per my application requirement.